# How to pass <li>text without replace the text on textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

I got school homework for today. I can pass the emoji to a textbox already but it will replace the previous emoji or text on the textbox if clicked. I want to know how to not replace the textbox text if I clicked and able to keep input emoji or text. Sorry for my bad english if you guys don't understand.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("ul").hide();
    $("input.btnemoji").click(function () {
        $("ul").toggle();
        $("ul.emoji li").click(function () {
            $("#ToSend").val($(this).text());
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<asp:Textbox id="ToSend" runat="server" Width="300px"></asp:Textbox>
<input type="button" class="btnemoji" value="&#x1F600;" />
<ul class="emoji">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Use `$("#ToSend").val($("#ToSend").val()+$(this).text())`

Comment: when you use `.val(value)` it replace the  old value by the new, you just have to *store* the old value and *concat* with the new

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add to the existing value you need to append to the `val()` in the `input` instead of replacing it each time. To do this you can pass a function to the `val()` method which handles the appending for you, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul").hide();

  $("input.btnemoji").click(function() {
    $("ul").toggle();
  });

  $("ul.emoji li").click(function() {
    var $li = $(this);
    $("#ToSend").val(function(i, v) {
      return v + $li.text();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ToSend" width="300px">
<input type="button" class="btnemoji" value="&#x1F600;" />
<ul class="emoji">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Also note that I moved the `$("ul.emoji li").click()` handler *outside* of the one for `.btnemoji` as you were repeatedly adding new event handlers each time the `ul` was toggled.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the shortest method. All you need is to use this:

```
$("#ToSend").val($("#ToSend").val()+$(this).text());
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("ul").hide();
    $("input.btnemoji").click(function () {
        $("ul").toggle();
    });
    $("ul.emoji li").click(function () {
        $("#ToSend").val($("#ToSend").val()+$(this).text());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="ToSend"/>
<input type="button" class="btnemoji" value="&#x1F600;" />
<ul class="emoji">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Toggle the menu a couple of times, then click one of the `li`. You'll see that the emoji you clicked is added N times

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#ToSend").append($(this).text());
```

User append function without using

Comment: Downvote wasn't mine, but this wont work. You cannot `append()` to a `value` property of an `input` element